# Can we get the source code from a .git folder of a project

Tags: git, security

I have a question related to git and security.

Assume that someone has access to your .git folder of your project.

Will he be able, in some ways, to get the source code of the project from that?

If yes, how will he do that?

I'm curious.

Thanks!

Comment: Git repositories are not encrypted. The database format is entirely open and documented. Multiple implementations exist to read it

Comment: Thanks for the response ^.^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Absolutely. All they have to do is clone it:

```
git clone C:\Repo\.git Copy
```

The content of the `.git` directory *is* the repository with all its [objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), [references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) and [packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles).

Cloning the `.git` directory is no different than cloning any repository. In fact, you can create a so called [*bare* repository](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) and you would get the same contents that you usually see in the `.git` directory:

```
git init --bare C:\Repo
```

Comment: Excellent bare repository reference, never knew they existed! kudos for that!